# Cannot activate Windows 2012r2 Standard

Tags: windows

Running cmd.exe as Administrator:

```
Slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
-->> it gives error: 
Windows Script Host
Error: 0x8007041D On a computer running Microsoft Windows non-core edition, 
run 'slui.exe 0x2a 0x8007041D' to display the error text.
```

and:

```
slui.exe 0x2a 0x8007041D
-->> 
Windows Activation
An error has occured
You can also contact Microsoft by phone to help resolve
this problem. 
Code: 
0x8007031D

Description: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Telnet is not installed. Cannot install it via Windows Features, gives error, maybe because it isn't activated.

Question: What is this activation error?

If I try with the:

```
Slmgr.vbs /skms kms_server:1688
```

I got the same error message, maybe a client-side problem?

Comment: Get putty to bypass telnet, and try to telnet to the kmsserver on port 1688 please

Answer (score 0):

Open up an elevated cmd prompt and enter the following commands to uninstall and reinstall the Product Key:

```
slmgr –upk 
slmgr –cpky
slmgr –rilc
slmgr –ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
slmgr –ato
```

**NOTE**: Useful commands for SLMGR

-dli -> Display License information

-dly -> Display detailed License Information

-upk -> Uninstall Product key

-ipk $key -> Install Product Key

-ato -> Activate Windows

-rearm -> Reset the Licensing Status of the machine

-cpky -> Clear product key from the registry

-rilc -> Reinstall System License Files

Also, you can open Server Manager -> Local Server -> Click your Product ID and Windows Activation prompt will popup.

However, if you plan to use volume activation, please refer to:

Volume Activation Overview for Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831612.aspx

Appendix A: KMS Client Setup Keys

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867.aspx

If you run Evaluation Versions, please refer to Evaluation Versions and Upgrade Options for Windows Server 2012.

[Source 1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f02c4ac7-65fa-4e1a-b713-34eee96aef2a/activate-server-2012?forum=winserver8setup) and [Source 2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/6ad853c8-bb88-4077-9c64-1d93c44b59fa/error-0x8007041d-on-a-computer-running-microsoft-windows-noncore-edition-run-sluiexe-0x2a?forum=winserver8gen)